# List of Articles form FeinCMS Content Typs

Tags: django, templates, feincms

my mission is to get a list of articles. This article come form a simple FeinCMS ContentType.

```
class Article(models.Model):
       image = models.ForeignKey(MediaFile, blank=True, null=True, help_text=_('Image'), related_name='+',)
       content = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text=_('HTML Content'))
       style = models.CharField(
                    _('template'),max_length=10, choices=(
                            ('default', _('col-sm-7 Image left and col-sm-5 Content ')),
                            ('fiftyfifty', _('50 Image left and 50 Content ')),
                            ('around', _('small Image left and Content around')),
                            ),
                            default='default')
        class Meta:
                abstract = True
                verbose_name = u'Article'
                verbose_name_plural = u'Articles'

        def render(self, **kwargs):
                return render_to_string('content/articles/%s.html' % self.style,{'content': self,})
```

I would like to use that in different subpages.

Now it would be great to get a list of all articels on the main page (my projects -> list of project1, project2, project3, ).

Something like: Article.objects.all()
Template:

```
{% for entry in article %}
    {% if content.parent_id == entry.parent_id %} #only projects
        <p>{{ entry.content|truncatechars:180 }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but i get a error "type object 'Articels' has no attribute 'objects'...
Do you have a smart idea? It would be grade to use Feincms ContentType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FeinCMS content types are [abstract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes), that means there is no data and no database table associated with them. Therefore, there's no `objects` manager and no way to query.

When doing `Page.create_content_type()`, FeinCMS takes the content type and the corresponding `Page` class and creates a (non-abstract) model which contains the actual data. In order to access that new, concrete model, you need to use [`content_type_for`](http://feincms-django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contenttypes.html#obtaining-a-concrete-content-type-model). In other words, you're looking for:

```
from feincms.module.page.models import Page
PageArticle = Page.content_type_for(Article)
articles = PageArticle.objects.all()
```